# Logistic regression - strange behaviour of the decision boundary when additional parameters are added

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, regression, logistic-regression

I am trying to build a logistic regression model for a dataset consisting of two parameters 
x<sub>1</sub> and x<sub>2</sub>, but instead of analyzing just the two of them, I have added their squares as well - x<sub>1</sub><sup>2</sup>, x<sub>2</sub><sup>2</sup> and x<sub>1</sub>· x<sub>2</sub>.

At the first glance everything looks fine and the error function is decreasing, but whilist drawing the plot of the decision boundary I have noticed, that after circa 500 iterations something strange happens to it.
Here is an animation of the error function as a function of iterations and a respective plot of the decision boundary:
[image]

Now,I interpret the decision boundary as a quadratic function
x<sub>2</sub>=f(x<sub>1</sub>), where
the relation between both parameters is given like this:
  0.5 = θ<sub>0</sub> + θ<sub>1</sub>x<sub>1</sub> + θ<sub>2</sub>x<sub>2</sub> + θ<sub>3</sub>x<sub>1</sub><sup>2</sup> + θ<sub>4</sub>x<sub>1</sub>x<sub>2</sub>
+ θ<sub>5</sub>x<sub>2</sub><sup>2</sup>

Here is the python code I use to do everything:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import log
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

def sigmoid(x):
    return 1.0 / (1.0 + np.exp(-x))

def loadData(filepath):
    source=""
    try:
        f = open(filepath, "r")
        source = f.read()
        f.close()
    except IOError:
        print("Error while reading file (" + filepath + ")")
        return ""
    raw_data = source.split("\n")
    raw_data = [x.split(",") for x in raw_data if x !=""]
    raw_data = np.matrix(raw_data).astype(float)
    return (raw_data[:,:np.size(raw_data,1)-1], raw_data[:,np.size(raw_data, 1)-1:])

def standardize(dataset, skipfirst=True):
    means = np.amin(dataset, 0)
    deviation = np.std(dataset, 0)
    if skipfirst:
        dataset[:,1:] -= means[:,1:]
        dataset[:,1:] /= deviation[:,1:]
        return dataset
    else:
        dataset -= means
        dataset /= deviation
        return dataset

def error(X, Y, Theta):
    "Calculates error values"
    v_sigm = np.vectorize(sigmoid)
    h_x = X @ Theta
    sigmo = v_sigm(h_x)
    partial_vect = (Y-1).T @ np.log(1-sigmo) - Y.T @ np.log(sigmo) 
    return 1/(2*np.size(Y, axis=0))*np.sum(partial_vect)

def gradientStep(X, Y, Theta, LR):
    "Returns new theta Values"
    v_sigm = np.vectorize(sigmoid)
    h_x = X @ Theta
    modif = -1*LR/np.size(Y, 0)*(h_x-Y) 
    sums = np.sum(modif.T @ X, axis = 0)
    return Theta + sums.T

X, Y = loadData("ex2data1.txt")
#add bias to X
X = np.append(np.ones((np.size(X, 0), 1)), X, axis=1)
added_params = [[x[1]**2, x[1]*x[2], x[2]**2] for x in np.array(X)]
X = np.append(X, np.matrix(added_params), axis=1)
#standardize X
X = standardize(X)
#create vector of parameters
Theta=np.zeros((np.size(X, 1), 1))

iterations = 3000

Theta_vals = []
Error_vals = []

for i in range(0, iterations):
    Theta_vals.append(np.asarray(Theta).flatten())
    Error_vals.append(error(X, Y, Theta))
    Theta = gradientStep(X, Y, Theta, 0.07)


#CALCULATING FINISHES HERE

#plot data:
fig = plt.figure()
def_ax = fig.add_subplot(211)
def_ax.set_xlim(np.amin(X[:,1:2]), np.amax(X[:,1:2]))
def_ax.set_ylim(np.amin(X[:,2:3]), np.amax(X[:,2:3]))
err_ax = fig.add_subplot(212)
err_ax.set_ylim(0, error(X, Y, Theta))
err_ax.set_xlim(0, iterations)
positive_X1 = []
positive_X2 = []
negative_X1 = []
negative_X2 = []
for i in range(0, np.size(Y, 0)):
    if(Y[i, 0] == 1):
        positive_X1.append(X[i, 1])
        positive_X2.append(X[i, 2])
    else:
        negative_X1.append(X[i, 1])
        negative_X2.append(X[i, 2])


err_ax.set_ylim(np.amin(Error_vals), np.amax(Error_vals))

def animation(frame):
    global Theta_vals, Error_vals, def_ax, err_ax, positive_X1, positive_X2, negative_X1, negative_X2
    def_limX = def_ax.get_xlim()
    def_limY = def_ax.get_ylim()
    err_limX = err_ax.get_xlim()
    err_limY = err_ax.get_ylim()
    def_ax.clear()
    err_ax.clear()
    def_ax.set_xlim(def_limX)
    def_ax.set_ylim(def_limY)
    err_ax.set_xlim(err_limX)
    err_ax.set_ylim(err_limY)
    def_ax.scatter(positive_X1, positive_X2, marker="^")
    def_ax.scatter(negative_X1, negative_X2, marker="o")
    Theta = Theta_vals[frame]
    res_x = np.linspace(*def_ax.get_xlim(), num=5)
    delta_x = [(Theta[4]*x+Theta[2])**2-4*Theta[5]*(Theta[3]*x**2+Theta[1]*x+Theta[0]-0.5) for x in res_x]
    delta_x = [np.sqrt(x) if x >= 0 else 0 for x in delta_x]
    minb = [-(Theta[4]*x+Theta[2]) for x in res_x]
    res_1 = []
    res_2 = []
    for i in range(0, len(res_x)):
            if Theta[5] == 0:
                res_1.append(0)
                res_2.append(0)
            else:
                res_1.append((minb[i]+delta_x[i])/(2*Theta[5]))
                res_2.append((minb[i]-+delta_x[i])/(2*Theta[5]))
    def_ax.plot(res_x, res_1)
    def_ax.plot(res_x, res_2)
    err_x = np.linspace(0, frame, frame)
    err_y = Error_vals[0:frame]
    err_ax.plot(err_x, err_y)


anim = FuncAnimation(fig, animation, frames=iterations, interval=3, repeat_delay=2000)
print(error(X, Y, Theta))
anim.save("anim.mp4")
```

What could be the reason of such a strange behaviour?

Comment: Does the first plot capture all the data you are fitting your model with? Logistic regression is for the most part a linear classifier, and I believe you are fitting to minimize the error. It indeed seems like the correct fit, because the model starts fitting the `blue` line when at around 500 iterations, swtiches to the orange line and starts to steadily decrese the loss while minimizing the error aswell. The overall model and fit doesn't seem strange in my opinion.

Comment: Well I have run it now for 6000 iterations and I will see what will happen. I expect that it might actually work as described, but all my data is shown on the plot. Another strange thing I have noticed, without major changes to the code it tends to produce theta values that make the equation unsolvable (has no real solutions for any x1 and x2, which is strange. I will have to dive into this a little bit more and will update the question later.